# How to keep derived state up to date with Apollo/GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

My situation is this: I have multiple components in my view that ultimately depend on the same data, but in some cases the view state is *derived* from the data.  How do I make sure my whole view stays in sync when the underlying data changes?  I'll illustrate with an example using everyone's favorite [Star Wars API](https://swapi.graph.cool).

First, I show a list of all the films, with a query like this:

```
# ALL_FILMS
query {
  allFilms {
    id
    title
    releaseDate
  }
}
```

Next, I want a separate component in the UI to highlight the most recent film.  There's no query for that, so I'll implement it with a client-side resolver.  The query would be:

```
# MOST_RECENT_FILM
query {
  mostRecentFilm @client {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

And the resolver:

```js
function mostRecentFilmResolver(parent, variables, context) {
    return context.client.query({ query: ALL_FILMS }).then(result => {
        // Omitting the implementation here since it's not relevant
        return deriveMostRecentFilm(result.data);
    })
}
```

Now, where it gets interesting is when SWAPI gets around to adding *The Last Jedi* and *The Rise of Skywalker* to its film list.  We can suppose I'm [polling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/#datastartpollinginterval) on the list so that it gets periodically refetched.  That's great, now my list UI is up to date.  But my "most recent film" UI isn't aware that anything has changed — it's still stuck in 2015 showing *The Force Awakens*, even though the user can clearly see there are newer films.

Maybe I'm spoiled; I come from the world of [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/) where stuff like this Just Works™.  But this doesn't feel like an uncommon problem.  Is there a best practice in the realm of Apollo/GraphQL for keeping things in sync?  Am I approaching this problem in entirely the wrong way?

A few ideas I've had:

- My "most recent film" query could also poll periodically.  But you don't want to poll *too* often; after all, Star Wars films only come out every other year or so.  (Thanks, Disney!)  And depending on how the polling intervals overlap there will still be a big window where things are out of sync.
- Instead putting the `deriveMostRecentFilm` logic in a resolver, just put it in the component and share the `ALL_FILMS` query between components.  That would work, but that's basically answering "How do I get this to work in Apollo?" with "Don't use Apollo."
- Some complicated system of keeping track of the dependencies between queries and chaining refreshes based on that.  (I'm not keen to invent this if I can avoid it!)

Answer (score 0):

In Apollo observables are (in components) over queried values (cached data 'slots') but your `mostRecentFilm` is not an observable, is not based on cached values (they are cached) but on one time fired query result (updated on demand).

You're only missing an 'updating connection', f.e. like this:

```
# ALL_FILMS
query {
  allFilms {
    id
    title
    releaseDate
    isMostRecentFilm @client
  }
}
```

Use `isMostRecentFilm` local resolver to update `mostRecentFilm` value in cache.

Any query (`useQuery`) related to `mostRecentFilm @client` will be updated automatically. All without additional queries, polling etc. - Just Works? (not tested, it should work) ;)

Comment: So the gist is: calculate the derived value alongside the original query and persist it as an object in the cache.  Now that it's an object in the cache, it can be observed.  I believe that would work, but it feels clunky.  Now instead of encapsulating my derivation logic in its own resolver, it gets leaked into another query.  It's viable, but doesn't really sound like a best practice.

Comment: ok, instead of polling, using subscription ... what is the source of change, what emits message, some observer over records counter or insert handler? usually the last one (if only one source of change, not shared db) ... and this is not only derived state, it's a kind of aggregator (over all records) ... what else? median order value in last month based on single item value? both should be backend jobs